# Fetch failed loading: GET "video URL". at ngsw-worker.js:2607

Tags: angular, google-cloud-storage, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

we have angular 6 universal application having videos in my website, I am getting 
below error  when I am clicking on the play button,

```
   ngsw-worker.js:2607 Fetch failed loading: GET "https://storage.googleapis.com/web-assets/videos/event/WCCICC2017/Interviews/Rama%20Mona/Rama%20Mona-360p.mp4".
```

but after some time video fetching and playing, but it's taking more time to play video. when i am removing ngsw-worker.js video fetching fast and playing.

after some time video fetching  and playing

```
Fetch finished loading: GET "https://storage.googleapis.com/web-assets/videos/event/WCCICC2017/Interviews/Rama%20Mona/Rama%20Mona-360p.mp4".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetch implementation in every major browser that the angular service worker uses does not properly handle requests for partial content, which is needed for fast video playback.  reference this bug opened with mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1477391

The work around here is to edit the generated service worker (ngsw-worker.js) to not route certain requests through the fetch API.  There is an open feature request with Angular to provide for this capability without rewriting the file, but it's not currently on the roadmap.

open ngsw-worker.js and locate the class Driver and modify it's onFetch function to include something like this near the top:

```
let re =/\.mp4$/; //write whatever regex is appropriate for your case
if (re.test(req.url)) {
  event.waitUntil(this.idle.trigger());
  return;
}
```

This way, the service worker will pass all requests matching your regex back to the browser to handle natively rather than passing through the fetch API.

To ensure it doesnt get overwrriten and you don't need to do this everytime you build / deploy, You should save your edited service worker as somehting like ngsw-worker-mod.js and register it as your worker in app.module like:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('./ngsw-worker-mod.js', {enabled: environment.production})
```

and make sure to include it in your angular-cli.json as an asset so that it gets included in your build outputs.

Comment: thanks for reply , i will add code , and check ,.but its not permanent solution for angular service worker..

Comment: it's currently the only actual solution besides not using angular service workers. Unfortunately angular doesn't currently provide a way to bypass the fetch API and the fetch API is broken when it comes to partial content requests.  I've used this solution in production for a media intensive application and it isn't at all difficult to maintain.  The only annoyance is having to make sure I update the new service worker when I update angular to get their updates.  Hoping to be able to stop once the fetch API is fixed or angular provides an actual solution.